# Is it possible to control vertical space using purely CSS?

Tags: css

I have a header bar with a logo on the left and a search form following. Both are floated to the left. I am trying to control the vertical spacing of the search form using CSS but I cannot find a good solution other than adding padding and/or margin either on top or bottom of the search form, and although I may be able to find values that work in one browser, it is not a solution that is consistent across browsers... The same problem exists if I have a search button next to the search field. Is there a solution for this that is cross-browser compatible or do I need to use JavaScript? Is there a standard to doing something like this?

P.S. I reset the CSS in my dev code.

Here is a simplified version of my header code:

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

#site-title, #search {
    float: left;
}

#site-title {
    margin-right: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 28px;
}

#search {
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 5px
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="site-title"><a href="#">Site Title</a></div>
        <div id="search">
            <form>
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." />
            </form>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

Link to code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mg535m80/2/

Edit: I found a solution, it's not as cross-browser compatible is I'd hoped, but it works in all modern browsers. I just added `display: flex;` and `align-items: center` to the parent, and it worked like a charm. New code:

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

#site-title, #search {
    float: left;
}

#site-title {
    margin-right: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 28px;
}

#search {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="site-title"><a href="#">Site Title</a></div>
        <div id="search">
            <form>
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." />
            </form>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mg535m80/9/

Comment: Can you elaborate about the differences you observes in the different browsers?

Comment: @MrLister For instance, in Chrome, I can add a top margin of, let's say 5px to the search form and it would look centered, then on Firefox, the search form would appear to be aligned more towards the bottom than the center

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the style of the `input`, which is different between browsers.

Solution: to make the input look the way you want, set all its styles explicitly instead of relying on the defaults. Example:

```css
input {
    width:10em; height:1.25em;
    margin:0; border:2px solid #888; padding:0;
    font:inherit; vertical-align:baseline;
}
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mg535m80/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to specify vertical properties in pure CSS. Partially you already answered your question (i.e. `padding` and `margin` properties). Other properties include `height`, `line-height`, `min-height`, `max-height`, etc. Also, you can use `position: absolute` or `fixed` and specify `top/bottom` properties. Hope this may help. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be set `height` in `header`:

```
header {
    height: 33px;
}
```

And then use `display: flex` to align search box:

```
#search {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/mg535m80/3/

Comment: This is a good solution, but what if the height of the header is unknown?